# Execute R command on specific termimal

Tags: r, linux, terminal

I am running R vscode on linux HPC node. I ran command in a R script (using ctrl + enter), but it was executed on a login node. I would like to execute the command in a specific terminal, where I have connected to a exe-node, when using ctrl + enter automatically.

Do you know how can I can setting this up?

I try copying in script and paste to the terminal but this could too much time for long script